# Search field within a form and then do something with all the chosen results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to offer the ability for users to open a form built using PHP/HTML and then on that form have a box which allows them to search for employees then want to send the form to without having to submit the form at this stage.

They will get a search box which allows them to enter the name or part name, the query then finds all employees which match the input string and they then choose the correct employee and that respondent is added to a list and they then search for the next employee and so on until they have added as few or many as they like.

Once they have selected the names, they then fill in some other standard fields on the form and then a separate entry is created in the "forms" table for each request sent.

Happy how to do the last part in terms of entering it into the database etc and how to do a "normal" search in PHP/MySQL but what should I do for the search within a form and add to the list pre submitting?

Comment: Yes Hidde is correct, people will be much more likely to answer your questions in the future the more you accept answers in the past and the higher your score is.

Comment: Happy to when the solutions answers the questions asked but they haven't always answered the questions I have asked which may well be a reflection on the questions I guess but out of 4 questions asked one was solved so was accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the technique you are looking for is AJAX which uses javascript to examine the form field as they type, talk to the php, get data, then show it back to the user without having to reload the page or sumbit the form.  The exact thing you describe is called auto complete which there are many prebuilt [tools](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) for (or you can build your own custom one with some js knowledge).  I am not going to try to post all the code here since it would be rather long and involved but if you search around these terms you will surely find what you need.

Comment: This gave me the answer - I found Jquery Autosuggest and, after some tinkering, I have got it to work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can all be achieved with Javascript.

If you have a small number of employees, you could send an array of employees with the page.  Use an 'onchange' event in the form field so that with each keypress you run a lookup matching the employees against the typed text.

It's likely that you don't have a small enough number of employees, and also I'm not sure best practice advocates sending your entire company address book inside a web page!  In that case you will need to do the same using Javascript ajax calls within the page.  On each keypress, fire a request back to the server asking for employees matching the text string.

You will need to dynamically display the matching employees in another form widget that allows for selection, or maybe as text with checkboxes etc.

There are plugins that manage all the client side part of this but you will still have to put together your own web service to do the employee lookup.